# Conversion of Python object to class

Tags: python, class, owl, ontology, owlready

I want to define an ontology in Python (owlready). All terms in owlready are defined as classes.
What I have already is something similar where some terms (that represent sections) are already defined as classes and others are objects within these classes (defined as Quantity objects). 
Is there a way to convert these objects to new classes?

Here is an example. `basis_set` would be defined in a class `section_basis_set`

```
class section_basis_set(Section):
    basis_set = Quantity(
                 type=str,
                 shape=[],
                 description='String describing the basis set'
                )
```

but I want something like

```
class section_basis_set(Section):
    is_a = [has_part.exactly(1,basis_set)]

class basis_set(Quantity):
    """String describing the basis set"""
    is_a = [has_type.some(string)]
```